# How to use field value from subclass in overloaded function in constructor

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

The problem can be illustrated in this code:

```
class A
{
    public readonly x;
    
    constructor()
    {
        this.x = this.getX();
    }

    protected getX()
    {
        return "X";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public readonly suffix = ko.observable("will change later");

    constructor()
    {
        super();        
    }

    protected getX()
    {
        return super.getX() + " " + this.suffix();
    }
}

console.log(new B().x);
```

The result is "X undefined", which is clearly unwanted, although it is expected considering "construction workflow" of TypeScript - mainly that the field `suffix` get its value only after super constructor has finished. But why is that? Maybe because while declaring it we could use something "super" before "super" actually exists? Is it a "chicken vs. egg" principle?

Unfortunately I ran into this problem too many times and sometimes I have to redesign things to cope with this. How to resolve this kind of "early field usage"? Is there any known pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current approach with assigning local members only after finishing `super` call looks irrelevant for your classes. But it gets very important for classes that override ancestor's members.

```ts
class A { x = 1 }
class B extends A { x = 2 }
```

Assigning `this.x = 2` *before* `super` call will lead to pretty unfortunate consequences.

I'm not fully aware about idiomatic solution to that kind of problem. But `getters/setters` look like a good fit for class members that could be initialized lately.

```ts
class A {
    public get x(): string { // implements readonly as it has no setter
        return this.getX()
    }

    protected getX(): string {
        return "X";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public readonly suffix = "will change later";

    constructor() {
        super();        
    }

    protected getX() {
        return super.getX() + " " + this.suffix;
    }
}

console.log(new B().x); // "X will change later"
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYJgzw)

Comment: This getter approach is a brilliant idea, exactly solves this kind of problems for me. To be more precise, by design the `getX` method should be called only once, so I wanted to store it in readonly field. But now I will have the getter and there I will return cached value.  [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NalJ0w)